# Android gradle plugin compatible with gradle version 4.4.1?

Tags: android, gradle

I've been fighting with my gradle settings for longer than I'd like to admit. I've won many small battles but now it has come down to this one burning question:

Which android gradle plugin is compatible with gradle version 4.4.1?

Thank you! I will appreciate your help forever if you can point me in the right direction.

(I'm running OS Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: tried `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha09` ?

Comment: I got an error just now using it:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: ok did you try switching to AS [3.1-r9](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/01/android-studio-31-canary-9-is-now_24.html)? do you really need gradle 4.4.1? 4.4 (that comes with AS 3.1-r9) is not good enough?

Comment: I've updated to AS 3.1-r9. Running gradle 4.4 and 
    com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha09. Gradle is syncing in android studio with no errors but when I execute react-native run-android in terminal I get:


    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)


I've searched stackoverflow. All solutions point to invalidating cache, deleting .gradle, then restarting android studio. 
I've done this but still getting the error in terminal.

Comment: tried brand new project?

Comment: That's probably a good idea after all the trouble I've been through. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: no, sorry, never seen that `GradleWrapperMain` ...

Comment: The new project works perfectly. The app is up and running on my android phone via USB connection. The other project I had nighmare-ish problems with was a git clone and I have no idea what went wrong, I tried to fix it for WAY too long, sometimes it's hard to let go of a sinking ship but I finally let go. Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: sure, your welcome